# Add a custom form to a WordPress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that is used as a news portal to generate traffic for my clients (leads). I want the ability to add a custom HTML code with the form in it.

The posted data (the form structure) contains several parameters that needs to be changed in each blog post in order to send the data to the relative campaign in my crm.

Form should display perfectly in mobile as well, thank you page is handled by the form attributes so no need to worry about that.

any tips?

Comment: You'll be better of asking this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: its sounds like you need a custom plugin to generate form and handle submissions...